# Book about teaching magic and an old stone

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

It's been more than ten years, but I've been thinking about a book I read as a kid. I can't remember any part of the title or author's name.

It begins with an old man who sits and ponders a stone in his hand constantly, which he's worn smooth. He takes on a boy or young man and teaches him the secret of magic by giving him progressively more physically difficult chores. The boy finally gets it when he's told to move an impossibly large boulder, but ends up yelling at it to move, which it does.

I remember that there were others who were taught magic, and the stone turns out to be some sort of magic orb, maybe a fallen star. These magicians are able to change into animals. It was a longer book, at least 700 pages. Hope someone can help...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The series is the Belgariad (Well, technically that only refers to the first 5 published books, but...), but specifically you are talking about the book [Belgarath the Sorcerer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgarath_the_Sorcerer), which talks about Belgarion's ultimate-great grandfather.

Comment: This sounds like the right one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like [The Belgariad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Belgariad) to me.

Comment: Yup, definitely. One of my all time favourite series, so it's quite bizarre to hear it described like that!

Comment: @Nellius I'm in the middle of reading it at the moment or I wouldn't have recognised it!