# What is this magic orb?

Tags: the-belgariad, magical-items

What is [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9531/6942) magic orb/stone? Is it the Orb of Aldur? And what is that?

Sorry to ask this question, but it has just been a while since I last read the series, and I kinda want a refresher in order to best understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the stone that the God Aldur is holding at the beginning of [Belgarath the Sorceror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgarath_the_Sorcerer) is the object that would eventually become the Orb of Aldur. At that point he's basically talking to it.

The Orb itself is a magical item that grants its wielder essentially unlimited power. However, it only allows itself to be wielded by those of a specific line, or those who are completely innocent. Gods are powerful enough to eventually force it to serve them, but Aldur didn't because that's essentially slavery.