# Fantasy book series with a wizards who frequently change into wolves

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a fantasy book series I read many years ago:

- It has a grandfather wizard who lives in a tower.
- His grandson who is also a wizard who becomes a king and his sister who is also magic.
- These characters often change into wolves. It even writes about how the wolf pack works.
- The world is overseen by a group of gods that are all related.

Comment: Aside from there being a family of wolves, do you remember any actual events (a quest, a villain to be defeated, a love to be won, etc)? What were the character names? Who was the main protagonist? How many years ago did you read it? You said it was a series, did you read all of them or just one of them?

Comment: Could this be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_of_Truth? There''s a bunch of wizards and wolves

Comment: Or this; More wolfy and less wizard-y; http://www.goodreads.com/series/50110-chronicles-of-the-cheysuli

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/book-about-teaching-magic-and-an-old-stone/

Answer (score 16):

Could it be possible that you are thinking of the [Belgariad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Belgariad) by David Eddings? The wolves kinda match, the hero of the books - Belgarion becomes a king. His Grandfather Belgarath is both a wizard and has a tower. Both of these characters turn into wolves. The part that doesn't match is that there is no sister involved. The principal female character is Polgara, Belgaraths daughter and Belgarions aunt. The gods of this world are all from the same 'family'.

Comment: i and welcome to stack exchange :) .. nice answer i think but try adding some link next time .. i recommend you take the tour and se the help center

Comment: It's certainly a possible match. I think the problem here is that we've got a pretty generic description of the (pretty generic) characters and no description of what they actually do in the books.

Comment: I think this must be it! The OP is probably thinking of Polgara with his 'sister'.